# Dynamic product images

Tags: product, image, product-list

Im trying to make product in specified category to have an overlay on its image, ex. "NEW/FRESH" on image.

I can handle image change, but I have no idea how/where I can in-time change product image...

Only solutions I found were including configurable products, which I don't want/need.

Some hints?

Comment: This is a very confusing question - am I right in saying you just want an additional image overlaid on your main product image if the product is new?  You'd normally do this mainly through CSS, you check the attribute in your template, if it's a new product you add markup to the template, the CSS of the markup has a background png image with transparency which you overlay on the top using z-index.

Comment: I just answered and realized that @McNab suggested this in the comments. Props to them - they should add an answer and you should mark that as accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having special images is unnecessary. I would do the following:

- Create a product attribute with a `yes/no` data type (boolean) and call it "New"
- Check in your media.phtml if the attribute is set:

  ```
  if($product->getNew()):
    $_imgsrc = $this->getSkinUrl('images/newbadge.png');
    echo "<img src='$_imgsrc' class='newbadge'/>";
  endif;
  ```
- Use CSS to position the image over top of the product image:

  `.imgsrc { position: absolute; z-index: 100; }`

**Edit:**

Fiddle demonstrating the technique: http://jsfiddle.net/aNCpn/

Comment: This is a much better answer.  I'll start answering rather than just commenting, good on you for doing it properly :)